# javascript ajax request in rails not able to pass values

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a rails application in which I have following controller action.

```
def index
   ....
   ....
      @currency = params["currency"].present? ? params["currency"] : "INR"
      @check_in_date = params["arrival_date"].present? ? params["arrival_date"] : Date.today.to_s
      @check_out_date = params["departure_date"].present? ? params["departure_date"] : (Date.today + 1).to_s
   ....
   ....
end
```

I have javascript where I am trying to make an ajax request like this.
  filename.html.haml

```
  else{
    hotel_id = id.slice(6)            
    $.ajax({
      url: "/single_hotel/"+hotel_id,
      data: {check_in_date: #{@check_in_date}, check_out_date: #{@check_out_date}, longitude: #{@longitude}, latitude: #{@latitude}, rooms: #{@rooms}, adults: #{@adults}, children: #{@children}, currency: #{@currency} },
      type: 'get'
    });            
  }
```

when I check the sources tab in chrome console I see this.

```
            $.ajax({
              url: "/single_hotel/"+hotel_id,
              data: {check_in_date: 2016-08-08, check_out_date: 2016-08-09, longitude: 34.854, latitude: 32.3213, rooms: 1, adults: 1, children: 0, currency: INR },
              type: 'get'
            });
```

When I try to make the ajax request I get "VM18204:52 Uncaught ReferenceError: INR is not defined".

Also if I remove currency and make the request I get following values for check in & check out dates.

```
[1] pry(#<Bookings::HotelsController>)> params
=> {"check_in_date"=>"2000",
 "check_out_date"=>"1999",
 "longitude"=>"34.854",
 "latitude"=>"32.3213",
}
```

Can someone please help me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this

```
data: {check_in_date: #{@check_in_date}, check_out_date: #{@check_out_date}, longitude: #{@longitude}, latitude: #{@latitude}, rooms: #{@rooms}, adults: #{@adults}, children: #{@children}, currency: #{@currency} }
```

try this

```
data: {check_in_date: "#{@check_in_date}", check_out_date: "#{@check_out_date}", longitude: "#{@longitude}", latitude: "#{@latitude}", rooms: "#{@rooms}", adults: "#{@adults}", children: "#{@children}", currency: "#{@currency}" }
```

Comment: I got this "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"